# Troubleshooting BSOD when connecting an Xbox controller

Tags: windows, device-manager, game-controller, xbox-one

I messed up my windows system pretty badly, and I don't have enough experience with windows to understand what I did. I have an Xbox One controller connected via a USB wireless dongle. I use the controller for input, and also as an audio output (it has an audio jack). The audio stopped working, so I opened the playback devices window, and disabled it, intending to re-enable it. It just disappeared, so there was no way to re-enable it.

I did another stupid thing: I opened the device manager, found the controller under "Audio devices", and disabled it there too. Again, it just disappeared, I couldn't enable it again. Further, my whole system crashed. It crashed again when I restarted it, and only stopped crashing when I turned off my controller. When I turned it on again, the system crashed again.

It seems to be a bug in windows, but I don't see how I can fix this without re-installing the OS, which I'd rather not do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. For the audio device:**

Hit the start button and in the search box type "*Manage audio devices*" and press enter.>

Select the playback tab.>

In the box that lists your devices, right click on any empty space.>

Click "*Show Disabled Devices*".

**2. For the disabled controller:**

Hit the start button and in the search box type "*Device Manager*" and select it.>

In the Device Manager window select **View**> **Show hidden devices**.

Comment: This is great, I didn't understand this. Problem is, the whole system crashes as soon as I turn on the controller.

Comment: I just reset my OS unfortunately. Thanks for the help though.